# Return backup when deferred fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

We are all familiar with [the `$.Deferred()` behaviour](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) when it succeeds and fails:

```
function foo() {
    var backup = 'bar', 
        dfd = $.ajax(...)
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        });

    return dfd.promise();
}

// outside the function
$.when(foo())
    .always(function(something) {
        // 'something' is either data, OR jqXHR, depending if the thing fails
    });
```

However, I have a backup result of `data`, known as `backup`, residing inside the function `foo`, that I'd like to return when the request fails.

Provided that I can neither change parameters set in `$.ajax(...)` (meaning I cannot add a "fail" handler), nor change the return type of `foo`, nor move `backup` outside `foo`, how can I achieve the following effect?

```
function foo() {
    var backup = 'bar',
        dfd = $.ajax(...)
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // replace return with 'bar', which is impossible 
            // because 'data' is undefined
            data = backup;
        });

    return dfd.promise();
}

// outside the function
$.when(foo())
    .always(function(something) {
        // 'something' is now some fresh data, or 'bar' if ajax fails
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own deferred object, instead of using the one returned by `$.ajax()`:

```
function foo() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var backup = 'bar';
    $.ajax(...)
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            def.resolve(data);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            def.resolve(backup);
        });

    return def.promise();
}
```

...

```
foo().done(function(data) {

});
```